# My Daily command for my discord bot is not working

Tags: python, discord.py

I am coding a discord currency bot with discord.py and the cooldown doesn't work.

It says:

```
File "main.py", line 106

await message.channel.send("You got 2500 discs")
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

when I run it.

```
if message.content == '|daily':
     @commands.cooldown(1, 86400, type=BucketType.user)
     await message.channel.send("You got 2500 discs")
     setdiscs(user, getdiscs(user)+2500)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Is your code inside an `async def` function? Have you read the [relevant FAQ](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#where-can-i-use-await) on exactly this question?

Comment: I think this is more likely a case of an old version of Python. The output for using `await` outside of an async context is slightly different: `SyntaxError: 'await' outside function`

Answer (score -1):

Decorators are used for functions.

If I were you, I'd consider using command decorators instead of the `on_message` event, as it makes command handling a hell of a lot easier, with regards to arguments, decorators etc.

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.cooldown(1, 86400, commands.BucketType.user)
async def daily(ctx):
    await ctx.send("You got 2500 discs")
    setdiscs(ctx.author, getdiscs(ctx.author) + 2500)
```

And if you're using command decorators, you'll want to `process_commands` in your `on_message` event like so:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    await bot.process_commands(message)
    # rest of your on_message code
```

---

**References:**

- [General decorator usage](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/decorators-python)
- [d.py Command Decorators](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html)
- [`BucketType.user`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.discord.ext.commands.BucketType.user)
- [`commands.Context`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context) - This is the first argument of every command using the command decorator in d.py
- [`Bot.process_commands()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.process_commands)

Answer (score -1):

A command cooldown works well, but if the bot restarts then the cooldown will be lost, so you should store your cooldown data in a file.

Create a file named `daily` in the same directory as your file with the contents:

```
{}
```

And try this code for your daily command:

```py
import math
import time

with open('daily', 'r') as f:
    daily = eval(f.read())

def save_daily():
    with open('daily', 'w') as f:
        f.write(repr(daily))

# ...

@client.event
async def on_message(message):

    # ...

    if message.content == '|daily':
        if (user in daily) and daily[user] > time.time():
            waittime = daily[user] - time.time()
            await message.channel.send(f'Please wait **{math.floor(waittime/3600)}h {math.floor((waittime/60) % 60)}m** to use this again!')
        else:
            await message.channel.send('You got 2500 daily discs!')
            setdiscs(user, getdiscs(user)+2500)
            daily[user] = time.time() + 86400

    # ...

    save_daily()
```